# React Native Countdown with pause function

Tags: javascript, react-native, time

Starting from a tutorial I'm trying to make my own countdown timer and I would like to add a pause function.
It uses moment.js

```
const [time, setTime] = useState({

    eventDate: moment.duration('00:00:06'),
    days: 0,
    hours: 0,
    mins: 0,
    secs: 0,
  });

const updateTimer = () => {
    const x = setInterval(() => {
      let {eventDate} = time;


      if (eventDate <= 0) {
        clearInterval(x);

      } else {
        eventDate = eventDate.subtract(1, 's');
        const days = eventDate.days();
        const hours = eventDate.hours();
        const mins = eventDate.minutes();
        const secs = eventDate.seconds();

        setTime({
          days,
          hours,
          mins,
          secs,
          eventDate,
        });
      }
    }, 1000);
  };
```

simple button that changes the state of Pause, this works

```
const handlePause = () => {
    {
      !pause ? setPause(true) : setPause(false);
    }
  };
```

but is not stoping useEffect

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (pause) {
      return;
    } else {
      updateTimer();
    }
  }, []);
```

probably everything is wrong but I had no other idea on how to do it.
Advises?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found it!
I added

```
 const [intervalTime, setIntervalTime] = useState();
```

and I set it at the end of the function

```
const updateTimer = () => {
    const x = setInterval(() => {
      let {eventDate} = time;

      if (eventDate <= 0) {
        clearInterval(x);

      } else {
        eventDate = eventDate.subtract(1, 's');
        const days = eventDate.days();
        const hours = eventDate.hours();
        const mins = eventDate.minutes();
        const secs = eventDate.seconds();

        setTime({
          days,
          hours,
          mins,
          secs,
          eventDate,
        });
      }
    }, 1000);
    console.log('interval', x);

    setIntervalTime(x); // set state

    };
```

then I use `clearInterval` in `handlePause`

```
  const handlePause = () => {
    {
      !pause ? setPause(true) : setPause(false);
    }
    clearInterval(intervalTime);
  };
```

Just added pause has dependency

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!pause) {
      return;
    } else if (pause) {
      updateTimer();
    }
  }, [pause]);
```